# How to make image brighter in 10 times? Python, OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and can't find the way how to make the image brighter in 10 times. I have exercise:

"The puzzle image is hiding another image.

- The green and blue values are all just random values in the range 0..255 ("snow" or "speckle noise")
- The data of the real image is exclusively in the red values
- In addition, the red values have all been divided by 10 (made dark)
- The green/blue snow is obscuring the real image
- Write code to recover the real image"

I'm trying to solve it using my code:

```
import cv2

color_image = cv2.imread('puzzle-gold.png')


print(color_image.shape)

cv2.imwrite('/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/python_red.png', color_image[:,:,2])
red_image = cv2.imread('python_red.png')
bright_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(red_image, alpha = 1, beta = 128)
cv2.imshow('Color red',bright_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your call to `cv2.convertScaleAbs()` looks like it is simply adding 128 to every channel of the image. First, you need to split the image and operate on only the red channel. Second, see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) for the meanings of the `alpha` and `beta` parameters.

Comment: thanks, I tried to find some information about it, but still don't understand. And yes, I know that now it just add 128 to every channel.

"First, you need to split the image and operate on only the red channel" You mean like this:
bright_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(color_image[:,:,2], alpha = 1, beta = 128)

Comment: @Nicolas Sure...